# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: sort is not a function react spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, react, typescript

```
var currStatus = '';
var job = [...this.state.data];
return <div>
    {
        job.length ?
            <div>
                {
                    Object.keys(job).forEach(jobTree) => {
                        job[jobTree].sortBy((leftItem, rightItem) => {
                            return leftItem.job.Title.localeCompare(rightItem.job.Title)
                        });

                        <div><h2>{jobTree}</h2></div>
                        this.state.data[jobTree].forEach((row) => {
                            if(currStatus != row.status.Title) {
                                currStatus = row.status.Title;
                                <div> <h3>{currStatus}</h3></div>
                            }
                        });
                    })
```

I used `sort()` to sort job alphabetically.

But I am getting an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Job[jobTree].sort is not a function

Answer (score 0):

The `sort()` method in Typescript/Javascript is used to sorts an **array** alphabetically.

So, make sure you are calling this method on **Array** variable.

1. [TypeScript - Array sort()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_sort.htm)
2. [JavaScript Sorting Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp)